# Can I use a void method with a label.setText?

Tags: java

My question is if it possible to use a void method in a setText for a Label? I'm working at the moment on school homework on Netbeans and I want to use the 'public void printTable()' in a Label but the programm always say that it is impossible to use a void here and I know that normally I should use a return statement but in the instruction is written that I should use a 'void'.

Here you can see my Java Class

```
public class AffineFunction  
{
  private int a;
  private int b;


public int getA()
{
    return a;
}

public int getB()
{
    return b;
}

public void setA(int newA)
{
    a = newA;
}

public void setB(int newB)
{
    b = newB;
}

public AffineFunction(int pA, int pB)
{
    a = pA;
    b = pB;

}

public int solve(int x)
{
     return (a*x)+b;
}

public void printTable()
{

    for(int i =-10; i<=10; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("F(" + i + ") = " + solve(i));
    } 

}

public void printTable(double step)
{
       for(double i = - 10 ; i<= 10; i = i + step)
    {
        System.out.println( "F(" + i + ") = " + solve((int)i));
    } 
 }
}
```

Here is a part of my JFrame :

```
             //E
    int a = Integer.valueOf(aTextField.getText());
    int b = Integer.valueOf(bTextField.getText());
    int x = Integer.valueOf(xTextField.getText());
    //T
    AffineFunction affineFunction = new AffineFunction(a, b);
    //S
    FLabel.setText(String.valueOf(affineFunction.solve(x)));
    printTableLabel.setText(String.valueOf(affineFunction.printTable()));
```

Comment: If you want to pass a value to a function, you'll need to return it from the function that generates it.  There's no way the text `printTable` sends to System.out can be passed to `setText()` because it returns `void`.   Perhaps your instructor meant for you to call `setText()` on the label inside of the `printTable` function?

Comment: Hello an thanks for the answer bu the instructor meant that this method should be a void because it doesn't return a value, just print it. However I tried using a return statement but I do not no how to use it on the method. If you have any idea that would be great.

Comment: you got the solution or should i post an answer ?

Comment: I don't get it. It would be great if you post the answer